# Um programa em C consegue saber em qual OS ele está compilando?

Tags: c, compilação

Estou desenvolvendo uma API multi plataforma em C e preciso saber se existe alguma forma de saber qual o OS está sendo compilado.

Por exemplo, poderia ser uma diretiva de pre compilação

```c
#ifdef LINUX
#include<linuxlib.h>
#elif OSX
#include<osxlib.h>
#elif WINDOWS
#include<rwindowslib.h>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Diretivas de preprocessador:

Windows: `_WIN32` (que, apesar do nome, também está disponível em 64 bits)
OS X (também inclui iOS): `__APPLE__`
Unix: `__unix`
Linux: `__linux`
Android Linux: `__ANDROID__`
iPhone: Não encontro nada, mas para versões especificas há o `__IPHONE_4_3`, etc. Note-se que apesar de serem versões específicas são na mesma verificadas em tempo de compilação.

Não tenho a certeza que as macros de iPhone estejam sempre disponíveis. Algumas fontes referem o `Availability.h` e o `TargetConditionals.h` portanto se não funcionar pode valer a pena tentar usar esses ficheiros.

Em tempo de execução, é possível descobrir a distribuição Linux que está a ser usada lendo, por exemplo, o ficheiro `/etc/lsb-release`

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente API's multiplataformas desenvolvem o código de forma específica para cada plataforma e não verificam tem tempo de execução. O código só é especificado em tempo de compilação para uma plataforma alvo.

Para isso, elas geralmente definem macros para verificar qual SO é.
É o que o **[Qt](https://github.com/mirror/qt/blob/4.8/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h?source=cc)** e o **[wxWidgets](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/page_cppconst.html)** fazem.

No cabeçalho da sua API você define:

```
#ifdef defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
#    define MEU_API_WINDOWS
#  endif

#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__linux)
#  define MEU_API_LINUX
#endif

#if defined(__APPLE__)
#  defined MEU_API_OSX
#endif

void foo();
```

Daí você pode definir seu código da seguinte forma:

```
void foo()
{
    #if defined(MEU_API_WINDOWS)
    // código para windows
    #elif defined(MEU_API_LINUX)
    // código para linux
    #elif defined(MEU_API_OSX)
    // código para OS X.
    #endif

    // etc
}
```

E com isso você precisaria de um só cabeçalho e a função foo() funcionaria em todas as plataformas que você planejou.

Alternativamente, você pode definir foo() em arquivos .c diferentes para cada plataforma (fica mais organizado), fazendo as verificações do SO em cada arquivo.

Por exemplo, para o `foo_linux.c`:

```
#ifdef MEU_API_LINUX
#include <lib_do_linux.h>

void foo() 
{
// TODO
}
#endif
```

E no `foo_windows.c`:

```
#ifdef MEU_API_WINDOWS
#include <lib_do_windows.h>

void foo() 
{
// TODO
}
#endif
```

---

Recomendo que dê uma olhada nas implementações do Qt e do wxWidgets pois ambos lidam bem com essa situação.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um arquivo de build para cada sistema, chamando o make com um parâmetro, e definir uma diretiva de compilação através de um parâmetro do compilador que você usa, ou então verificar a documentação do compilador e dos arquivos de cabeçalho que ele usa por padrão, para ver se ele já não define algumas diretivas para você.

Uma dessas é a `_WIN32`, já consagrada desde o surgimento do Windows em 32 bits, para diferenciá-lo do Windows 16 bits. Já para o Windows 64 bits, você pode usar `_WIN64`, mas veja que _WIN32 ainda assim estará definido.

[Macros Predefinidas pelo VS2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b0084kay(v=vs.120).aspx)

[Macros predefinidas no GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565979/macros-for-gcc-g-to-differentiate-linux-and-mac-osx)

Comment: Interessante Miguel Angelo como seria a sugestão do Makefile?

Comment: Dentro do Makefile você vai ver os comandos lá dentro (e.g. `gcc -o foo.o foo.c` se estiver usando o GCC) então basta adicionar no comando `-d $(NOME_OS)` [**referência**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), sendo que existiria um batchfile para iniciar o make em cada OS: win32.bat => make NOME_OS=WIN32; win-phone.bat => make NOME_OS=WINPHONE... [**referência**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273608/how-to-pass-argument-to-makefile-from-command-line) e por ai vai

Comment: Mas isso não evita que eu tenha de criar um arquivo para cada plataforma =/ que no caso seria o arquivo batch.

Comment: Não evita não, mas já simplifica absurdamente a manutenção desses arquivos... quer dar suporte a um novo OS, basta criar um arquivinho BATCH super-símples. Se não for assim, você vai ficar a mercê do compilador definir as diretivas como _WINXX, __linux. A não ser que exista um detector command-line capaz de fazer isso, e que seja portado para os mais diversos sistemas operacionais.

Comment: Minha resposta estava confusa... editei ela.